# How to call one method from one class to another class in Python unitest

Tags: python, unit-testing, appium-android

```
@pytest.mark.usefixtures("beforeClass", "beforeMethod")
class ContentTest(unittest.TestCase):

    def test_basic_content_ad(self):
        self.cad.click_on_ad()
        self.cad.click_on_ex_ad()

    def test_recycler_view_ad(self):
        self.cad.navigate_back_to_screen()
        self.cad.click_on_recycle()
```

another file

```
@pytest.mark.usefixtures('beforeClass', 'beforeMethod')
class AppTest(ContentAdTest, unittest.TestCase):

    def test_app_install_ad(self):
        self.cad.click_on_app()
```

I want to call the test_recycler_view_ad method in Apptest class

how Can I do?

Comment: Syntax is usually classname.methodname(arguments)

Comment: You need to create an instance of ContentTest class, then call that method

Comment: @OneCricketeer Thanks! but can you please elaborate the same or help me to do so

Comment: `ContentTest().test_recycler_view_ad()`, however it'd make more sense to extract this function to a shared module if both tests will use it